# Getting to charts embedded in Excel worksheet

Tags: perl, excel, com, ole

I am trying to do some modification to charts in Excel worksheet using the following Perl code:

```
    $ex = Win32::OLE->new ('Excel.Application')
        or confess "could not instantiate Excel.Application: $!\n";

    my $workbook = $ex->Workbooks->Open ($file)
        or confess "failed to open $file: $!";

    my $charts_ws = $workbook->Worksheets ("Charts");
    my $charts_col = $charts_ws->ChartObjects;

    for (my $i = 0; $i != $charts_col->Count; ++$i)
    {
        my $chart = $charts_col->Item ($i); # XXX the problem is here
    }

    $workbook->Close;
```

Everything seems to work until the `XXX` marked line. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x800a03ec
    in METHOD/PROPERTYGET "Item" at test.pl line 557
```

I was not able to decipher what is the `0x800a03ec` HRESULT value about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Why do I always find the answer few seconds after I post a question here?)

Solution: I should have used `$charts_ws->ChartObjects ($i)->Chart` and I should start the loop from index 1.